# The messages app isn't on my Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, messages

Recently, I've been wanting to send and receive texts on my MacBook air, just like I do on my pro, but when I spotlight 'messages,' nothing shows up except for java and json files. 
[image: Searching for 'messages' in spotlight]

Is there any way to download the messages app off of the app store (I've looked and haven't found it. Is it called something else there?)
How could I get the messages app on my computer?
Thanks
-A
Edit: I have checked to make sure my spotlight works properly, and looked through my applications folder. It is not present.

Comment: Have you verified that `Messages.app` is completely not present in your `/Applications` folder? If it is there, then your problem is only with your Spotlight index.

Comment: Yes, I have @NetherLinks

Comment: I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1):

Since `Messages.app` comes bundled with OS X, it seems that it got deleted somehow.

To get the Messages app again (or any other pre-installed OS X app that is not available on the App Store), you will have to [re-install OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18868?locale=en_US). The process does not erase any data.

Alternatively, if you know someone who has the same OS X, you could copy `Messages.app` from their machine and paste it in your Applications folder.